# how do i enable WED and SAT in Jquery Calender

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

i need to enable Only WEDNESDAY AND SATURDAY in whole year in JQuery Datepicker.

Kindly suggest me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: We have no idea what you're talking about. Please clarify your question and add code showing what you have tried.

Comment: Already these days are enabled in jquery calender. What specific you want?

Comment: Do you mean: ONLY Wednesdays and Saturdays to be selectable ?

Comment: yah @Sammatti i want to enable only Wed and Sat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are looking to achieve, [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) is what you are looking for.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 4 && day != 5 && day !=0), ''];
    }
});
```

There could be a more elegant way to figure out the day of the week, but I shall let you figure that out.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vX4St/)